# Custom Data-type in Java

Tags: java

For an application I need to have an unsigned data-type with 24 bits.
Unfortunately such a data type is not available in Java. I’m planning to implement it as a new class.But I’m not sure about the performance of such an implementation.

Is it advisable to write my own class?

If it is advisable, is it possible to good performance?

Comment: How many of these will there be active in your application at any one time? Unless you're talking about an amount on the order of millions, you're better off just using an integer and "wasting" 8 bits per datum, instead of trying to optimize where you don't need to.

Comment: @Anon, +1. I would have upvoted that if it was an answer.

Comment: Thanks Anon. I'm writing an indexer for a simple desktop search engine. So using 24-bit unsigned integers instead of 32-bit integers I hope I will be able to save some space.

Comment: If you just want to save space, then writing your own class is not a solution, because for each object there is some overhead, you'll not be able to create an object that takes up less memory than a 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save space, you could use int for caluclation and map the least significant 3 bytes to a byte[] or just three bytes:

```
  public static byte[] convert(int i) {
    return new byte[]{ (i & 0xff0000) >> 16, (i & 0xff00) >> 8, (i & 0xff) };
  }

  public static int convert(byte[] b) {
    if (b == null && b.length != 3)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();

      return (b[2] << 16) | (b[1] << 8) | b;
  }
```

(can't verify if it is bug free but at least it should give an idea)

Comment: +1 Thanks, this seems like a good solution for my problem.Also Let me ask a little question. Can't we use byte array such as byte[] value = new byte[3]  instead of int data-type in order to represent actual value of the number.

Comment: Calculating an index value based on `int` is by far easier then doing it on a `byte[]`. I'd leave the calculation `int` based and convert the index to an array (or three bytes) just to persist them. You could wrap the `byte[]` into a Integer24Bit class or so, but then you won't save space anymore.

Comment: Note that you won't save any space by storing a byte[3] for each value, since each array has its own overhead. You want to store all your integers in one large byte[], and have some method of calculating where each one begins (if each one is exactly 3 bytes, it can just be array[index%3]).

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, you mean implement it as a class which uses a larger data type and bounds checking, like this:

```
public class Unsigned24 {
    private static final MAX_UNSIGNED24 = Math.pow(2, 24) - 1;
    private static final MIN_UNSIGNED24 = 0;

    private final int value;

    public Unsigned24(int value) {
        if (value > MAX_UNSIGNED24 || value < MIN_UNSIGNED24)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("value out of bounds: " + value);
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

// ... other methods, such as equals(), comparison, addition, subtraction, etc.
}
```

This would work, but might not be worth the trouble. Also, it doesn't really take only 24 bits of memory, but rather 32 plus the overhead for an object.

It really depends on your goals. Why do you want a 24-bit integer.

Is it just because you have bounds-constraints on the values? If so, you might want to do something like the above.

Is it because you have a lot of them, and want to save memory? If so, you might want to build some class that abstracts an array of 24-bit integers, and internally saves them consecutively in a byte-array.

Is it because you are interfacing with some hardware or network interface that expects exactly 24 bits? In that case, you might want to look at the java.nio classes.

Comment: Avi's right.  Unless you absolutely need the bounds checking, you'd be better off just using an int.

Comment: Math.pow(2, 24) - 1 == 0xffffff

Comment: Thanks Avi. I'm writing an indexer for a simple desktop search engine. So using 24-bit unsigned integers instead of 32-bit integers I hope I will be able to save some space. Therefor I think your second option (byte-array) might be more practical for my scenario.

Comment: Have you looked into standard indexer / search engines, such as lucene? Also, there are much more efficient ways of storing large numbers of unsigned integers, such as variable-length encoding (http://www.answers.com/topic/variable-length-quantity), gamma encoding, and others, which are commonly used in search-engine indexes.